# dispose my object in thread to get efficient memory usage

Tags: c#, multithreading, video-streaming, rtsp, dispose

I am using Accord.Net to show RTSP video stream in a worker thread as you can see :

Main_Form:

```
     VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
     Thread Proceso1;
     Proceso1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(updateui));
     Proceso1.Start();
```

And my function     :

```
public void updateui()
      {
               reader.Open(RTSPAddress);

                while (true)
                {
                    Bitmap frame1 = reader.ReadVideoFrame();

                    pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage = frame1;
                }
        }
```

It works fine for some seconds but after that i get out of memory exception .So i want to know how can i dispose all object in thread?

Comment: Dispose `frame1` like `frame1.Dispose( );` and close `reader` also like `reader.Close()`

Comment: @Aria What about picturebox ?

Comment: @Aria where should i close the reader?

Comment: in `updateui()` after `while` and also dispose `frame1` after `pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage = frame1;`

Comment: @Aria but   reader.Close(); is a unreachable code

Comment: Yeah, the main issue is that every iteration of the `while` loop is creating a new bitmap, but they are not being explicitly destroyed. However, Aria's suggestion to dispose `frame1` I think will be getting rid of the wrong bitmap. You want to dispose of the previous frame, not the current one, so get a reference to `pictureRTSP.BackroundImage` before assigning a new frame to it, then assign the new frame, then dispose of the old one.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson thank you .could you please give me in detail?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson i changed my code to this but i get invalid parameter exception .why   
                while (true)
                {
                    Bitmap frame1 = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
                    pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage = frame1;
                    var oldImg = pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage;
                    if (oldImg != null) oldImg.Dispose();
                    //Do whatever with the frame...
                }

Comment: I think you're on the right track, just got the wrong order. Hang on a second, I'm writing an answer. You can format code in a comment by surrounding it with the `tilde` character on either side: `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every iteration of the `while` loop is creating a new bitmap, but they are not being explicitly destroyed. Every time you read a frame and update the display, you need to dispose of the previous frame:

```
public void UpdateUI() // C# naming conventions
{
    reader.Open(RTSPAddress);
    while (true)
    {
        Bitmap previousFrame = pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage;
        Bitmap currentFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
        pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage = currentFrame;
        if (previousFrame != null)
            previousFrame.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This should help, but there's still some other issues that you need to work out:

- What happens if an exception is thrown while trying to read the next frame?
- What happens when you reach the end of the video stream?
- What happens if the code above runs faster than the frame rate of the video?

Comment: Thank you .but in this line Bitmap previousFrame = pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage; i get this error :Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Image' to 'System.Drawing.Bitmap'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Can i change it to this :                    Bitmap previousFrame =(Bitmap) pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage;

Comment: You don't need to, you can change the line above to this: `var previousFrame = pictureRTSP.BackgroundImage;`

Comment: after some minutes i get this exception :{"Parameter is not valid."}

Comment: See bullet point number 2 in my answer. I'll let you address these points on your own, and if you are still stuck after trying, then post them as new questions on the site

Comment: what you mean :What happens when you reach the end of the video stream?.

Comment: Have a look at `reader.FrameCount` - there is only a finite number of frames in a video, and eventually you will reach the last frame. After that, it doesn't make sense to try and call `reader.ReadVideoFrame()`, and trying to do so will probably make it throw an exception

Comment: I ask my problem in another post